# Why when I make a change to a project on xcode the previous project is affected?

Tags: xcode, swift

I recognize that I'm new in using Xcode but I noticed A very strange behavior from XCODE, when I clone a project and I make changes in the Localizable.strings. these changes are automatically reflected in the previous project that was cloned.
So i have each time to update it, and when I update it the new project is affected.
Do you have any clue to stop this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it would be either user error, you keep opening the same file, or the clone is in the same directory as the original so it edits them both because Xcode doesn't know which one to actually edit.

What to try:

1. Make sure you are opening two separate files when you check.
2. Quit Xcode entirely and open the project again.
3. Move either the original file or the clone to a different folder. EX: Move it from desktop to downloads or documents
4. Change the name of the file